# Best way to organize a website root

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, directory-structure

I have made a website (WP based) and put every stuff inside the `/site` folder.

I did that, thinking of creating "custom" systems, and putting each one inside a folder, so for example: `/promo` would go to something else than the website...

But, I have tried with both `.htaccess` redirect and PHP `location` redirect, and when I try to "share" the website, without it's /site folder included, Facebook doesen't detect's the site meta...

Also, is it a problem for google, to use redirect's when accessing the website without the `/site` WP home folder? I mean, a guy comming from a www.onesite.com would have it's "referer" header as onesite, or mysite?

Thanks

Comment: If you're posting it on facebook why can't you just post the full link and retrieve the metadata?  What do you mean by .htaccess redirect....  Are you redirecting?  Why not just use .htaccess to set /site as the index?

Comment: @CharlesAddis The main problem is, if someone tipe `www.mysite.com`, then it will not work, as the index.php or the .htaccess will be redirecting... Facebook just doesen't "follows" up pages... =/

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding you.  Is english your first language?  If you post the link on facebook - nobody will have to type it in (so long as they are coming from facebook.)  If you altered your .htaccess file correctly when a user goes to www.site.com your web server will redirect the request to www.site.com/site and thus www.site.com/index.php will never be loaded (assuming your using a php file to redirect).  Basically without altering .htaccess your user will have to go to /index.php before going to /site/index.php

Comment: You're not specifically redirecting from site.com/index.php to site.com/site/.  You need to set site.com/site as your index.

Comment: My problem is: the root is under `/site` folder. If I go to Facebook, type in www.mysite.com, then there will be no meta found, and the shared post will be empty. But if i access the `www.mysite.com` i will be redirected correcly. The problem here is: Facebook doesen't follows redirects... how do i solve that?

Comment: Thats why I said go to facebook and type /site...  Your users don't have to remember your link if you are posting a hyperlink to it.

Comment: When i say "I" i might be saying someone else... visitors will not remember the /site! i will...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set /site to be your INDEX root folder.  That way when user goes to site.com your server routes the request to /site but does not reflect this in the address bar.  This is what I have been trying to say.  Do you speak English well or something cause your either too stupid or too stubborn to understand what I am saying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24407/discussion-between-charles-addis-and-ivan-seidel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you're creating your own problems. Just put WordPress in document root and don't bother with rewriting to a subdirectory. WordPress won't delete any custom files or folders when updating.

If you have some custom part that you want to reach through http://www.example.com/promo. Put it in the `promo` folder under the document root.

If want to reach the custom part through http://promo.example.com, just create new [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).